# CMAKE for modular c++ framework

Tags: c++, cross-platform, build-process, cmake, modularity

I'm refactoring a large platform independent c++ framework so that it's libraries and execuables no longer have to be in the same directory (or even repository) and it is proving quite challenging. The framework was currently used only by me and it should now address our whole working group so I have to keep it as modular and as automatized as possible.

My basic structure looks like this

- apps/

  - app1, app2, ...
- libs/

  - core, lib1, lib2, ...
- bin:

  - app1, app2, libcore, liblib1, liblib2, ... (on NIX)
  - app1.exe, app2.exe, core.dll, lib1.dll, lib2.dll, ... (on Windows)

**Apps** depend on **libs**, and all libs depend on the **core** lib. This all works fine in the same root directory and with the **add_subdirectory** mechanism.

Project dependencies were handeled by the order in which I was calling **add_subdirectory**: first **libs** (core being the first), then **apps**. Cmake was kind enough to set ${core_SOURCE_IR} to the respective directory and all binaries (libs and apps) were generated in the same directory.

What I need advice with is:

- should I move to a **find_package** based approach (write for each lib and FindLib.cmake file)
- how the **apps** and **libs** will find each other
- where to put the binaries
- how to pass along include directories of dependent targets
- **ExternalProject_Add** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can `add_subdirectory()`es in any order without caring about dependencies. CMake handles them when all CMakeLists.txt are parsed.

Second, if you wish any your lib or app to be buildable stand-alone, you certainly should use something like `find_package()`. It can be `find_library()` and `find_file(lib.h)` for simple cases.

In this case after `find_package()` invocation you will have LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS, LIB_LIBRARY_DIRS, LIB_LIBRARIES variables defined, which can be passed to `include_directories()`, `link_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()` respectively. That's how apps will find libs.

As for where to put binaries - in *NIX it's wide practice to place them into `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin`.

Please comment on this answer, if there is something unclear for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, my biggest concern with find_package() was how to synchronize all the Find[MYPROJECT].cmake files accross all other projects. Since I have one **core** library, Findcore.cmake sould be copied (or somehow available) to all projects that depend on it. 
Even with copying Find***.cmake files I will test it to see how it scales for my requirements.

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't be copied. You should define `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` pointing to your library install location (or `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` in case of Find*.cmake files). Also, you can create `YourLibConfig.cmake` instead of `FindYourLib.cmake`, it seems to more suit your needs, see this link: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file .

Comment: This was very cool. I updated all my libs to have `MylibConfig.cmake` files and now I can find them quite easily by setting `Mylib_DIR` before the I call `find_package( Mylib )` :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using `INSTALL(TARGETS...` along with `INSTALL(EXPORT...`

For full details, run:

```
cmake --help-command INSTALL
```

`FIND_PACKAGE` is generally used to find an external project which is already installed (and which wasn't installed with CMake's `INSTALL(EXPORT...` command) and `ExternalProject_Add` is used to download, configure, build and install an external project.

If you use `INSTALL(EXPORT...` with each of your libs and exes, and then just `INCLUDE` the installed `<target>.cmake` in your main CMakeLists.txt, these will become available as proper CMake targets, with their dependencies per configuration already set.

As to where to install these export files - that's up to you, but as long as the path you specify is the same place you use when you `INCLUDE` the file later, it should work fine.

Comment: +1 for INSTALL EXPORT. The mechanisms behind this may seem dauntingly complex at first, but I found it's really the only way to make modularized builds like this work without having the user to manually fiddle with library paths all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I read the description of the INSTALL command and I agree with ComicSansMS, it is a little daunting and very promising. Do you know of any example or some good practices guidelines online?

Comment: Try this: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets#Exporting_Targets

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. Since this library will be used by others it will be quite hard to ensure that the `INSTALL path` would be the respected. I have opted to build static libs and mark their paths in a `MylibConfig.cmake` file. Been using it for over a week on Ubuntu and Mac and it works quite well. I'll keep install in mind if things get more complicated ;) Thanks again

Comment: Things did get more complicated and now I started using INSTALL for my include files, libs and execs in addition to `MYLibConfig.cmake`. I also figured out how to manage the `INSTALL path` on linux and osx. 

I've hit a wall though on how to also export the project's configuration so that it can be found by other projects (via `find_package`). It this the right way to use `INSTALL`?

Comment: If you're using the `INSTALL` command, you shouldn't need `MYLibConfig.cmake`.  Just use [`INSTALL(EXPORT...`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:install) and it will automatically generate cmake files.  There will be a top-level one which is all that other projects need to `INCLUDE`, e.g. MyLib.cmake.  It then refers to the other generated cmake files, each of which specifies the requirements for a single configuration, e.g. MyLib-debug.cmake, MyLib-release.cmake, etc.  Another project then just calls `INCLUDE(<path to>/MyLib.cmake)`, and all your targets are imported.